# SQL query to get ID from multiple inputs

Tags: sql

I'm not sure the title is clear, but this is the situation.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID    inputID    value
4     1          10
4     2          20
4     3          100
6     1          15
6     2          20 
6     3          44
```

I have user input that gives me the values for inputID 1 and inputID 2, after which I want to get the ID to get the other information corresponding to that ID.

Example: If the user gives inputID(1)=10, inputID(2)=20, I want to get 4

Using simple AND statements don't solve this problem. I have asked already asked a few people, but I can't seem to solve this seemingly simple problem.

Comment: Are the pairs inputId-value unique?

Comment: @harshit Together they are, there will be only one ID that meets both conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE
  t1.inputID = 1 AND t1.value = @input1 AND
  t2.inputID = 2 AND t2.value = @input2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID from T as T1
where inputID=1 and value=10
      and EXISTS(select id from T where ID=T1.ID and inputID=2 and value=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
Create Table #tmp ( Id int, inputId int, value int)

insert into #tmp values (4,1,10)
insert into #tmp values (4,2,20)
insert into #tmp values (4,3,100)
insert into #tmp values (6,1,15)
insert into #tmp values (6,2,20)
insert into #tmp values (6,3,44)

-- my query
Select top 1 id from 
(Select id,count(id) as cnt from #tmp where (inputId=1 and value=10) OR (inputId=2 and value=20) Group by id) tbl
order by cnt desc

-- Scoregraphic's query
SELECT t1.ID
FROM #tmp t1
INNER JOIN #tmp t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE
  t1.inputID = 1 AND t1.value = 10 AND
  t2.inputID = 2 AND t2.value = 20


Drop table #tmp
```

On seeing the execution plan my query is takes overall 23% and ScoreGraphic's query takes 21%